# Display Google pie chart when mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css, google-visualization

I want to display my chart when the mouse is hover some element. Everything works fine except I can't stop the slideToggle returns its original position.

Once the mouse is "out-of-target" it contracts, but if the mouse still at the chart it should stay appearing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#test").hover(function () {
                $("#chart_div").slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
```

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrOSs/FDpd4/) for this question instead of pasting here the whole bunch of code.

EDIT

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/SGUbC/) is a goal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by defining both mouseenter and mouseleave events like this sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#chart_div").show('slow');
    });
    $(".outerClass").mouseleave(function() {
        if(!$('#chart_div').is(':hover')) {
            $("#chart_div").hide('slow');
        }
    });
});​
```

Where your html structure should resemble this sample:

```
<div class="outerClass">
    <div id="test"><strong>TEST.</strong></div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div id="another_div">here is out of the pie div</div>
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FDpd4/10/)

Comment: I don't get why is not hiding once the mouse left the chart. I tried your live example with firefox and IE 8+ and still the same. Is it working perfectly for you?

Comment: well, it will only disappear when mouse is out of 'outerClass'. It seems silly on this example but that might work on a well constructed-crowded html structure.

Comment: I will check your last one tomorrow, and accepted of course. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to change this to a `.click()`

but if you need the chart to display when you move your mouseover TEST and hide when you move your mouse back over test then you `.mouseenter()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#chart_div").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fnTXQ/